# R strsplit with multiple unordered split arguments?

Tags: r, split

Given a character string

```
test_1<-"abc def,ghi klm"
test_2<-"abc, def ghi klm"
```

I wish to obtain

```
"abc"
"def"
"ghi"
```

However, using strsplit, one must know the order of the splitting values in the string, as strsplit uses the first value to do the first split, the second to do the second... and then recycles.

But this does not:

```
strsplit(test_1, c(",", " "))
strsplit(test_2, c(" ", ","))

strsplit(test_2, split=c("[:punct:]","[:space:]"))[[1]]
```

I am looking to split the string wherever I find any of my splitting values in a single step.

Comment: Actually `strsplit(test_1, c(" ", ","))` does not work for me. It returns: `"abc def" "ghi klm"`

Comment: You are right.  I removed it.  I still want to add a working example using multiple split values if you have one.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Actually `strsplit` uses grep patterns as well. (A comma is a regex metacharacter whereas a space is not; hence the need for double escaping the commas in the pattern argument. So the use of `"\\s"` would be more to improve readability than of necessity):

```
> strsplit(test_1, "\\, |\\,| ")  # three possibilities OR'ed
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"

> strsplit(test_2, "\\, |\\,| ")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

Without using both `\\,` and `\\,`  (note extra space that SO does not show) you would have gotten some character(0) values. Might have been clearer if I had written:

```
> strsplit(test_2, "\\,\\s|\\,|\\s")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

@Fojtasek is so right: Using character classes often simplifies the task because it creates an implicit logical OR:

```
> strsplit(test_2, "[, ]+")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"

> strsplit(test_1, "[, ]+")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

Comment: how about strsplit(test_2, "[, ]+")

Comment: also `strsplit(test_2, "[[:punct:][:space:]]+")` for OP's updated request.

Answer (score 9):

In case you don't like regular expressions, you can call `strsplit()` multiple times:

```
strsplits <- function(x, splits, ...)
{
    for (split in splits)
    {
        x <- unlist(strsplit(x, split, ...))
    }
    return(x[!x == ""]) # Remove empty values
}

strsplits(test_1, c(" ", ","))
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
strsplits(test_2, c(" ", ","))
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

**Updated** for the added example

```
strsplits(test_1, c("[[:punct:]]","[[:space:]]"))
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
strsplits(test_2, c("[[:punct:]]","[[:space:]]"))
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

But if you are going to use regular expressions, you might as well go with @DWin's approach:

```
strsplit(test_1, "[[:punct:][:space:]]+")[[1]]
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
strsplit(test_2, "[[:punct:][:space:]]+")[[1]]
# "abc" "def" "ghi" "klm"
```

Answer (score 6):

You could go with `strsplit(test_1, "\\W")`.

Comment: You could go with strsplit(test_1, "\\W+").

Answer (score 1):

```
 test_1<-"abc def,ghi klm"
 test_2<-"abc, def ghi klm"
 key_words <- c("abc","def","ghi")
 matches <- str_c(key_words, collapse ="|")
 str_extract_all(test_1, matches)
 str_extract_all(test_2, matches)
```

Comment: Generally one should include `library` calls to load required packages that go beyond the "base" and "recommended set of packages. (That is especially true when you use functions that are not easily found with the use of the `??` operator and which require the prior installation of two of the beyond-base packages.)