# How do i atribbute different parameters to the function strsplit(split = " ")?

Tags: r, string, split, strsplit

as the title of the question says, i want to know how do i atribbute different parameters to the function

```
strsplit(x, split = " ")
```

If i apply it, i get every word in my string as a single vector, when it is separeted by space-bar. Ok. But the point is, i want also to split words that are connected with a dot (like banana.apple turning to "banana" and "apple").

I tought something like this (below) would work, but it doesnt...

```
strsplit(x, split = " ", "[.]")
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple characters to split with? (Both space and period?)

Comment: Surely this has been asked before. Have you tried any searches?

Comment: Yeah. I mean, i have a big string (with a lot of words) and some of them have dots between; others have space-bars; others have commas... I want to use these variety of punctuation to split the words... not only the space-bar

Comment: I've searched for a answer for a while.... but i dont get any

Comment: It's interesting to see how may duplicates there are, but not all of them are exact duplicates. The cited one is the best match amount the first 4 I looked at. The downvote is for the apparent lack of any searching. You should describe efforts at searching if you want to avoid the appearance that there was none. My search was on "[r] split multiple characters". (Seemed obvious.)

Comment: @IRTFM, I'm not sure that's the best dupe. Perhaps [this is more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10738729/1270695) as it seems like they're not looking at splitting into columns, which I got with ["r strsplit multiple split"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+strsplit+multiple+split).

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1  The key missing bit of knowledge was how to use the "|" (pipe/OR) operator in regex patterns. The OP thought you could just add quoted characters separated by commas. So maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738729/r-strsplit-with-multiple-unordered-split-arguments is better, but I cannot substitute it for the earlier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you want to split on both:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("banana.apple turning.something")
str_split(x, "[\\.\\s]") 
# [[1]]
# [1] "banana"    "apple"     "turning"   "something"
```

Comment: Why not just stick with base R and do `strsplit(x, "[ .]")`?

Comment: ohhhhh, thats it!!!! thank u very much!